# django iterate through model objects that contain another particular model object in a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models in my django app.

```
class author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class book(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()
    authors=models.ManyToManyField(author)
```

A author definately have written multiple books. A single book can also have multiple authors.

I want to iterate through all books by a particular author. Till now I have tried

```
for b in book.objects.filter(authors__name='HiDe'):
    print(b)
```

which gives `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'` probably because authors in book is a ManyToManyField.

Adding `books=models.ManyToManyField(author)` will make the database large and cumbersome to manage as an author can have too many books, so this is not the solution I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you define the `book`?
It seems it is just a function. Not a model object.
The error tells you `books` doesn't have the attribute `objects`, and is a function.

It is also generally good practice to capitalise the first letter of Django models.

Comment: Well `book` is clearly defined as a class, so why does this happen?
This error however didn't occured on the following operation.
`for a in author.objects.filter(name='HiDe'):    print(a)`